# Error detected while processing BufRead Autocommands

Tags: vimrc, gvim

I'm a new user and I have just installed GVim on my linux.  I just have ~/.vimrc file and no .vim folder may be because I did not install any plugins.

When I try to refresh (by :e) or reopen the buffer containing a specific type of files (*.inp). I get the following error.

```
Error detected while processing BufRead Autocommands for "*.inp"..function dist#ft#Check_inp[2]..FileType Autocommands for "*"..function <SNR>17_LoadFTPlugin:
line    3:
E1269: Cannot create a Vim9 script variable in a function: s:cpo_save
```

My ~/.vimrc looks as follows:

```
colorscheme evening
set guifont=Monospace\ 11
" visualizes line number
set number
set nocompatible
syntax enable
syntax on
" autoupdates file
set autoread
filetype plugin indent on
" sets the window to maximized when opened
set lines=999 columns=999
" updates file after buffer change
au FocusGained,BufEnter *.* :checktime
" keymap for :e = reloading the current buffer
nnoremap <F5> :edit<CR>
" list the contents of the current folder
nnoremap <F6> :!ls<CR>
" source ~/.vimrc
nnoremap <F7> :so $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

Could somebody please explain to me why I get this message and how to solve it ?

Comment: That might well be a bug in `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` or `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/dist/ft.vim`, but I don't see any `cpo_save` in a vim9 context in those files. Might be worth reporting on the mailing list or GitHub, esp. if you can reproduce with something like `vim -u DEFAULTS`

Comment: I can reproduce it with ```vim -u DEFAULTS```.  I'm going to file a bug report in GitHub.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Please report back with an answer if you get some feedback from GitHub. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [mailing list discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/vim_dev/c/IviBixM1Rkg) confirmed a bug in the abaqus.vim ftplugin, which has since been patched.

Options for the current user are (according to lacygoill on the mailing list):

1. Wait for the next runtime files update; then, build vim yourself or wait for your package manager to update.
2. Download the latest version of the file with patches to override the current file (see below).
3. Idem. using the current `$VIMRUNTIME` copy (see below).

---

Shell commands for (2):

```bash
curl --fail --location --show-error --silent --output ~/.vim/ftplugin/abaqus.vim https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vim/vim/master/runtime/ftplugin/abaqus.vim
<~/.vim/ftplugin/abaqus.vim sed '/let b:undo_ftplugin = "let s:cpo_save = &cpoptions|"/,/^$/s/s:/b:/g' >~/.vim/ftplugin/abaqus.vim.new && mv ~/.vim/ftplugin/abaqus.vim.new ~/.vim/ftplugin/abaqus.vim
```

Vim commands for (3):

```
:call mkdir($HOME . '/.vim/ftplugin/', 'p')
:edit $HOME/.vim/ftplugin/abaqus.vim
:read $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/abaqus.vim
:silent 90,94 substitute/s:/b:/
:write
```